# Wordpress get_template_directory_uri() not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is header.php code, in which I use `get_template_directory_uri()` which is not working for me it's not detecting css file,js files and all the files for which i am using `get_template_directory_uri()`

I am using wamp and I already enabled rewrite_module in wamp.

**Header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></title>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/layout/styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/layout/scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/layout/scripts/jquery.jcarousel.setup.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper col1">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1><a href="index.html"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
      <p><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){

  get_template_part("inc/slider");
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not the right way to include css and js files use wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() instead

Comment: What @VidyaLB said. Also, if you echo `get_template_directory_uri()` in the page what do you get?